# jqGrid Subgrid in Struts2 how to use onSubGridRowExpanded

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, struts2

I am just trying to implement a grid with subGrid in struts2 
using `<sjg:grid>` tags. When user clicks on `+` mark I want to send that main grid `cellvalue` as parameter to the action class to get the custom data for the subgrid. 
 For this I have taken reference from this link[jq Subgrid example](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asubgrid_as_grid#definition) 
My problem here is can use that example with tags in struts2.

As I have done some research i  found this solution but this is not workin

```
$.jqGrid('#gridOne').on('onSubGridRowExpanded',function(subgrid_id, row_id){

alert("THis is in Event");
});
```

so When user clicks on `+` mark the alert message is not getting displayed

If you want any further code let me know. I have very lame knowledge in jquery. thanks in advance.

EDIT:

THis is [How to get the grid cell value when user press + mark in main grid to get the subgrid data](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/get-column-value-on-click-of-the-button-for-subgrid-expansion/)  the exact problem That I am having just tell me how to achieve this solution in struts 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to worry about sending the param. You can use formIds in the sub-grid to let the sub-grid submit that form on load.

Apart from this, the subgrid also submits an `id` param to the loading url, viz. the key value of the selected row.

https://github.com/coding-idiot/Struts2-Examples - It contains sub-grid examples for better explanations.

Comment: I have seen those examples .. I think I have not found What I needed .. Or may be I need better explanation..  When user expands subgrid I need to send cell value of that particular cell to action to get the `JSON` data for my `subgrid`  .. Is this possible IF so please explain me Detail. Thank you very much  ..

Comment: Finally .. I came to know Where I am missing .... I have included the `key="true"` attribute in `<sjg:gridColumn>` tag to get the cell value of particular grid. .. Thank you @coding_idiot